# Asp.net post multiple parameters to javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

**index.cs**
If i post one value below method works.

```
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("Pass", "<script>pass('" + sle_password.Text.Trim() + "');</script>");
```

If i post multiple value like below **it does not work**

```
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("Pass", "<script>pass('" + sle_password.Text.Trim() + "','" + sle_username.Text.Trim() + "','" + txt_reseller_ID.Text.Trim() + "')";</script>");
```

**JS Code:**

```
function pass(pass, usrname, resellerId) {
            alert(pass,usrnameresellerId);
        }
```

Edited first code

Where i miss in second part code ?

Comment: You have an extra double-quote in your second code snippet.

Comment: may you please post code i will accept best answer thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("Pass", "<script>pass('" + sle_password.Text.Trim() + "','" + sle_username.Text.Trim() + "','" + txt_reseller_ID.Text.Trim() + "');</script>");
```

Comment: it is working i will accept best answer 5 minutes later stackover does not let me accept your answer as best :) thanks for solved problem